# Network latency under Hibernate/c3p0/MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, c3p0

I'm connecting to a MySQL (InnoDB) database over a connection with fairly high latency (~80ms) but relatively high bandwidth.

I've noticed that query times vary dramatically depending on how the query is issued.  In the following examples I'm performing a query for a single, small row by primary key.  The query times are:

- Command line client (`mysql`): ~160ms
- Raw JDBC:  ~240ms
- Hibernate: ~400ms (~0ms begin, ~160ms get, ~240ms commit)
- Hibernate, L2:  ~240ms (~0ms begin, ~0ms get, ~240ms commit)
- Hibernate, c3p0:  ~880ms (~160ms begin, ~240ms get, ~480ms commit)
- Hibernate, L2+c3p0: ~640ms (~160ms begin, ~0ms get, ~480ms commit)

("L2" means Hibernate second-level caching was enabled, "c3p0" means c3p0 was enabled, "begin", "get" and "commit" are timings for the various sub-methods invoked during the query)

These are, roughly, "steady state" results, so the L2 cache is hot, and Hibernate startup time is ignored.  I'm assuming that "get" is typically 0ms when the L2 cache is enabled because no get is actually issued.

My questions are:

- Why are all of the queries such large multiples of the network latency?  Even the `mysql` command-line client seems to require 2 round-trips for a simple query.
- Why are all of the JDBC/Hibernate queries so much slower than the command-line client?  Even the raw JDBC client seems to require 3 round-trips.
- Why does c3p0 seem to make everything worse?  I have, as far as I can tell, disabled connection testing, which could otherwise explain things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have advice specific to your problem, but there are a few debugging techniques that will help you figure out what's going on.  If you can add a connection parameter to the connection url, the JDBC driver will log basically everything going over the wire with timings:

jdbc:mysql://server/database?profileSQL=true

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

The other way you can look at this is to watch your network trafic through tcpdump.  mk-query-digest from the Maatkit tools can read the dump output and help you figure out exactly what's going on:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/07/01/gathering-queries-from-a-server-with-maatkit-and-tcpdump/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Those JDBC profiling options look very useful.  Hopefully I don't have to drop down to tcpdump, but great to know about the Maatkit tools :)

Answer (score 0):

- If you use spring, use a lazydatasource so as to only open the connection once you actually use it
- Try with BoneCP instead of c3p0 for better performance.

Comment: We're not using Spring, but BoneCP looks quite nice.  I'll give it a try and report back.